# i have nested array value i want to find groupId and want show that particular group message and senderId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
 "user": [
        {
            "_id": "5d9c1e6ca242212f800c041a",
            "group": [
                {
                    "createdAt": "2019-10-08T05:28:12.104Z",
                    "message": [
                        {
                            "sendAt": "2019-10-08T05:28:12.103Z",
                            "_id": "5d9c1e6ca242212f800c041c",
                            "senderId": "03",
                            "message": "msgbody"
                        },
                        {
                            "sendAt": "2019-10-08T07:06:21.139Z",
                            "_id": "5d9c356d2f672f0bc47e68a2",
                            "message": "message changed"
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id": "5d9c1e6ca242212f800c041b",
                    "groupId": "3",
                    "groupName": "name changed"
                }
            ],
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)‘s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too - despite it‘s „harsh“ title.

Comment: I tried this and i am getting all detail but i only want senderId and message   Sender.find({"group": {
        "$elemMatch" :{
            "groupId" : req.body.groupId
        }
    }},(err,user)=>{
        res.json({'user':user})
    })

Comment: Please add an [mcve] to your answer by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58299020/edit).